# what does "nulled script" mean?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm learning about web development and I just came across the term "nulled script". I googled it, but I still don't get it. What does it mean? I don't really understand how open source php, javascript web software in a LAMP environment can be protected or at least how the software can call home if it's modified or transfered to a new server... I would be great if somebody could explain it in a few words. Thanks. (Just to make it clear: I don't want to steal code. I am interested in protecting my own code.)

Comment: You can never protect javascript code, it is executed on the client side in the browser.  You need to go read about the differences between client and server side programming.  As for a "nulled script", never heard of it.

Answer (score 6):

A nulled script is when somebody changes a script to remove the protection implemented by the author. For example, when they remove call homes or registration checks or etc. These scripts are commonly distributed by shady/warez sites.

Although nearly impossible to detect from original author, I have no idea of the legal implications from removing call-home code in a script, javascript code has to be accessible to be of any use and is not compiled. As for removing copyrights and licensing information in a script, (also very hard to detect) this is pretty much illegal as far as I know.

Comment: seems a very vague question but everything above looks good to me!